# Google Analytics for Android wrong version

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, google-analytics-firebase

I have a problem with Google Analytics for Android. I followed the docs here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

The tracking doesn't work, I can't see anything in Analytics for a week, even though the logs looks good:

```
04-15 10:58:28.643: V/GAV3(4080): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
04-15 10:58:28.663: I/GAV3(4080): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
04-15 10:58:28.683: V/GAV3(4080): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread
04-15 10:58:29.043: V/GAV3(4080): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
04-15 10:58:33.768: V/GAV3(4080): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store  PATH: https:  PARAMS: ul=en-us,  ht=1397552303580,  sr=768x1184,  aid=com.myapp,  cid=9ea053f1-6f3c-4b95-a55b-14764aac91d6,  av=1.5.0,  v=1,  adid=303e7cc6-52e2-4d93-8916-123923587620,  t=appview,  an=myapp,  ate=0,  tid=>UA-15792067-3,  _u=.nKK-AL,  cd=/,  
04-15 10:58:33.808: V/GAV3(4080): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode initiated.
04-15 10:58:33.838: V/GAV3(4080): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode terminated.
04-15 10:58:33.838: V/GAV3(4080): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Dispatch running...
04-15 10:58:33.898: V/GAV3(4080): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/3.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; Nexus 4 Build/KOT49H)
04-15 10:58:37.612: V/GAV3(4080): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/3.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; Nexus 4 Build/KOT49H)
04-15 10:58:37.903: V/GAV3(4080): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: sent 1 of 1 hits
```

I suspect that it's because the log says `GAV3` (that is, version 3?) and I followed the docs for v4. Yet, I have no idea how to install v4, it's supposed to be installed.

My Google Play Services Lib version is: 4.3.23 (1069729-030), revision 16 in SDK manager.

Is it possible that this version doesn't contain v4? V4 was released less than a month ago, on the other hand from Google Play Services 4.3.23 is the latest version in the SDK manager I can see.

Is there anyone who works with v4? If so, can you check the versions for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GAV3` tag is a bug in the SDK and will be fixed in the next version. You can ignore that.

I am not sure but it looks like there might be an issue in copy-pasting the tracking id. There seems to an extra `>` before the tracking id. Can you make sure that the tracking id is of the format `UA-XXXXX-y`?

If this doesn't fix the issue, I'll try to dig for more pointers. Also, Can you make sure that the logging is on and on verbose so that I can look at more logs?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that was a really stupid typo that wasted 2 days of my life! All I needed is a second pair of eyes, thank you so much for looking into this!

Comment: Avi, how did you get that GAV3 in logs is a bug of v4? For the moment I see in logs:
`V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/3.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; ru-ru; Nexus 4 Build/KOT49H)`

And it drives me crazy :)